# Debug iPhone Mobile Safari without Web Inspector

Tags: iphone, ios, development, python

I'm using [Pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097?mt=8), a mobile Python environment to code on my iPhone while I'm on the train with no laptop around. I've started working on a small web application using [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) and [d3.js](https://d3js.org/). However, finding javascript errors in Safari is impossible. There is simply no way to find out what error stopped the application.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. It's a little dirty but it works and it helps a lot with scripting for the browser.

Simply put a `try...catch` block around the code you're want to debug and use `alert()` to output the information to you. Like this:

```
try {
  // some code that might go wrong
catch (e) {
  alert(e);
  alert(e.stack);
}
```

Comment: Not a programmer (so hammer away...) There are alternative browsers any of them (iCab, etc.) offer a debug mode?